# WPML vs WordPress 3.5

Tags: wordpress

I have my own WordPress site with version 3.4x.

I used the WPML plugin (version 2.6.0) for multilingual on my site. It had worked properly until I upgrade my WordPress core to latest version (3.5).

When I accessed my site, with WP_DEBUG is turned on, the homepage just displayed an error below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/domain.com/public_html/html/wp-includes/query.php on line 3569
```

I tried to upgrade the WPML plugin to the latest version (2.6.2) but the error still there.

If I deactivated the plugin so my site was OK excepted some notices about missing defined variables/constants from WPML plugin.

I contacted to the author of WPML plugin but not yet received any response.

Thanks,

Noat

Answer (score 0):

I already contacted to the author of WPML plugin.

He sent a beta version of the plugin and the problem was solved.

Hope this information will be useful for everyone that gets this situation.

Comment: there is a support forum on wordpress.org for each plugin, questions of this nature should be aimed at the plugin author via that forum first. but thanks updating with the answer. you should accept it.